Client side elements do not load on initial page until the page is clicked - Next.js
Client side elements do not load on initial page until the page is clicked.
It happens only for the first time visit. For subsequent visit this problem doesn't appears.
I am using next.js app router based solution, and using useEffect we are calling the API.
I also tried using "SWR" library from next.js to call the api. But the problem remains.
So to simplify the problem is, useEffect is not calling until the page is clicked.
We are also using Vercel hosting, and I couldn't reproduce the problem in my local system.
Thank You for your help!
  useEffect(() => {
    loadVisualTags();

    // On certain pages no need to call api after initial load
    if (
      categoryType == CategoryType.allThings ||
      categoryType == CategoryType.eventsOnly
    ) {
      return;
    } else if (categoryType == CategoryType.weeklyEvent) {
      // For weekly events type `weeklyEvent` extra customization
      const _today = createTodayBasedOnTimezone(Default.timezone, new Date());
      const todayName = dayName(Default.locale, Default.timezone, _today);
      const todayNameToAccessId = todayName as keyof typeof WeeklyTagsIds;
      const selectedWeeklyEventTagId = WeeklyTagsIds[todayNameToAccessId];

      dispatch({
        type: "setSelectedVisualTagId",
        payload: selectedWeeklyEventTagId,
      });
    } else {
      onScrollingLoadMorePosts();
    }
  }, []);

Full code:
"use client";

import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import PostCategoryListItemCard from "./PostCategoryListItemCard";
import { PostTagsLocation } from "@/prisma/AdvancedType";
import { DotWave } from "@uiball/loaders";
import { InfiniteScroll } from "./InfiniteScroll";
import lodash from "lodash";
import { shouldShowRandomPosts, WeeklyTagsIds } from "@/app/config/Behavior";
import { PostsResponse } from "@/app/api/posts/route";
import { Default, Strings } from "@/app/config/Default";
import { BaseCategory } from "@/app/config/Category";
import {
  createTodayBasedOnTimezone,
  dayName,
  differenceBetweenDates,
  excludeTimeFromDate,
  formatDate,
  nextWeeklyDate,
  utcDateTimeFrom,
} from "@/app/helper/EventDateTimeHelper";
import ButtonExploreMore from "./ButtonExploreMore";
import { CategoryType, Location, Tag } from "@prisma/client";
import PostVisualTags from "./PostVisualTags";
import CalendarWidget from "./CalendarWidget";
import { ClarityEvents, logClarity } from "@/app/helper/UIFunctions";
import FilterPopupDialog from "./FilterPopupDialog";
import FilterButton from "./FilterButton";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

type ActionType =
  | { type: "setIsFetching"; payload: boolean }
  | { type: "setPage"; payload: number }
  | { type: "setHasMore"; payload: boolean }
  | { type: "setPosts"; payload: PostTagsLocation[] }
  | { type: "setVisualTags"; payload: Tag[] | undefined }
  | { type: "setSelectedVisualTagId"; payload: number | undefined }
  | { type: "setSelectedDate"; payload: Date | null }
  | { type: "setFeaturedPosts"; payload: PostTagsLocation[] }
  | { type: "setShowFilterPopupDialog"; payload: boolean }
  | { type: "selectedLocationIds"; payload: number[] }
  | { type: "setTempSelectedLocationIds"; payload: number[] };

interface Store {
  isFetching: boolean;
  page: number;
  hasMore: boolean;
  posts: PostTagsLocation[];
  visualTags: Tag[] | undefined;
  selectedVisualTagId: number | undefined;
  selectedDate: Date | null;
  featuredPosts: PostTagsLocation[];
  showFilterPopupDialog: boolean;
  selectedLocationIds: number[];
  tempSelectedLocationIds: number[];
}

const reducer = (state: Store, action: ActionType): Store => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "setIsFetching":
      return { ...state, isFetching: action.payload };
    case "setPage":
      return { ...state, page: action.payload };
    case "setHasMore":
      return { ...state, hasMore: action.payload };
    case "setPosts":
      return { ...state, posts: action.payload };
    case "setVisualTags":
      return { ...state, visualTags: action.payload };
    case "setSelectedVisualTagId":
      return { ...state, selectedVisualTagId: action.payload };
    case "setSelectedDate":
      return { ...state, selectedDate: action.payload };
    case "setFeaturedPosts":
      return { ...state, featuredPosts: action.payload };
    case "setShowFilterPopupDialog":
      return { ...state, showFilterPopupDialog: action.payload };
    case "selectedLocationIds":
      return { ...state, selectedLocationIds: action.payload };
    case "setTempSelectedLocationIds":
      return { ...state, tempSelectedLocationIds: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

interface Props {
  categoryName: string;
  cityName: string;
  categoryType: string | null;
  locations: Location[] | undefined;
}

const Posts = ({ categoryName, cityName, categoryType, locations }: Props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    isFetching: false,
    page: 0,
    hasMore: true,
    posts: [],
    visualTags: undefined,
    selectedVisualTagId: undefined,
    selectedDate: null,
    featuredPosts: [],
    showFilterPopupDialog: false,
    selectedLocationIds: [],
    tempSelectedLocationIds: [],
  });

  const [locale, setLocale] = useState<string>(Default.locale);
  const [timezone, setTimezone] = useState<string>(Default.timezone);

  const [lastElementRef] = InfiniteScroll(
    state.hasMore ? onScrollingLoadMorePosts : () => {},
    state.isFetching
  );

  function initializePosts() {
    dispatch({ type: "setPage", payload: 0 });
    dispatch({ type: "setHasMore", payload: true });
    dispatch({ type: "setPosts", payload: [] });
    dispatch({ type: "setFeaturedPosts", payload: [] });

    Cookies.set(Strings.isMuted, "true");
  }

  function onScrollingLoadMorePosts() {
    loadMorePosts(
      categoryName,
      cityName,
      state.page,
      false,
      state.selectedVisualTagId
    );
  }

  function loadMorePosts(
    category: string,
    city: string,
    pageNum: number,
    removeOldPosts: boolean,
    visualTagId?: number,
    eventDate?: string,
    requestedFeaturedPost?: boolean
  ) {
    dispatch({ type: "setIsFetching", payload: true });
    const url = `/api/posts?c=${category}&city=${city}&p=${pageNum}&vt=${visualTagId}&ed=${eventDate}&rfp=${requestedFeaturedPost}&locids=${state.selectedLocationIds}`;

    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((postResponse: PostsResponse) => {
        // Featured posts
        dispatch({
          type: "setFeaturedPosts",
          payload: lodash.shuffle(postResponse.featuredPosts) ?? [],
        });

        if (!postResponse.posts) {
          dispatch({ type: "setIsFetching", payload: false });
          dispatch({ type: "setHasMore", payload: false });
          return;
        }
        if (postResponse.posts.length <= 0) {
          dispatch({ type: "setHasMore", payload: false });
        }
        const randomNewPosts = shouldShowRandomPosts(categoryName)
          ? lodash.shuffle(postResponse.posts)
          : postResponse.posts;

        if (
          categoryName === BaseCategory.events ||
          postResponse.categoryType == CategoryType.allThings ||
          postResponse.categoryType == CategoryType.eventsOnly
        ) {
          randomNewPosts.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.startDatetime == null || b.startDatetime == null) {
              return 0;
            }

            let dateA: Date = new Date(a.startDatetime);
            let dateB: Date = new Date(b.startDatetime);
            const today = new Date();

            if (a.eventRecurrence === "weekly" && dateA <= today) {
              const diffInDays = differenceBetweenDates(today, dateA);
              dateA = nextWeeklyDate(new Date(a.startDatetime), diffInDays);
            } else if (a.eventRecurrence === "daily" && a.endDatetime != null) {
              const dailyDateEndDate = new Date(a.endDatetime);
              if (today >= dateA && today <= dailyDateEndDate) {
                dateA = today;
              }
            }

            if (b.eventRecurrence === "weekly" && dateB <= today) {
              const diffInDays = differenceBetweenDates(today, dateB);
              dateB = nextWeeklyDate(new Date(b.startDatetime), diffInDays);
            } else if (b.eventRecurrence === "daily" && b.endDatetime != null) {
              const dailyDateEndDate = new Date(b.endDatetime);
              if (today >= dateB && today <= dailyDateEndDate) {
                dateB = today;
              }
            }

            const dateTimeA = dateA;
            const dateTimeB = dateB;

            if (dateTimeA > dateTimeB) {
              return 1;
            } else if (dateTimeA < dateTimeB) {
              return -1;
            } else {
              return 0;
            }
          });

          dispatch({ type: "setHasMore", payload: false });
        }

        if (
          postResponse.categoryType &&
          postResponse.categoryType == CategoryType.allThings
        ) {
          const extraPosts = postResponse.extraPosts ?? [];
          const mergedPosts = [...randomNewPosts, ...extraPosts];

          dispatch({
            type: "setPosts",
            payload: [...mergedPosts],
          });
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: "setPosts",
            payload: removeOldPosts
              ? [...randomNewPosts]
              : [...state.posts, ...randomNewPosts],
          });
        }

        dispatch({ type: "setIsFetching", payload: false });
        dispatch({
          type: "setPage",
          payload: removeOldPosts ? 1 : state.page + 1,
        });

        setLocale(postResponse.locale);
        setTimezone(postResponse.timezone);
      });
  }

  function loadVisualTags() {
    const url = `/api/category/visualTags/${categoryName}`;

    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response: { tags: Tag[] }) => {
        dispatch({ type: "setVisualTags", payload: response.tags });
      });
  }

  // Calendar
  const isEventsOnlyCategory =
    categoryType == CategoryType.eventsOnly ||
    categoryType == CategoryType.allThings;
  const [showingCalendar, setShowingCalendar] = useState(false);

  function reloadPosts(dateStr: string) {
    initializePosts();
    loadMorePosts(
      categoryName,
      cityName,
      0,
      true,
      state.selectedVisualTagId,
      dateStr
    );
  }
  function onSelectedDate(date: Date | null) {
    setShowingCalendar(false);
    dispatch({ type: "setSelectedDate", payload: date });

    if (
      excludeTimeFromDate(date) != excludeTimeFromDate(state.selectedDate) &&
      date != null
    ) {
      reloadPosts(date.toString() ?? "");
    }
  }

  function removeSelectedDate(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    onSelectedDate(null);
    reloadPosts("");
  }

  function gotoNextDate() {
    const tomorrow = state.selectedDate ?? new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    onSelectedDate(tomorrow);
    reloadPosts(tomorrow.toString());
  }

  // Use Effects
  // starting point
  useEffect(() => {
    loadVisualTags();

    // On certain pages no need to call api after initial load
    if (
      categoryType == CategoryType.allThings ||
      categoryType == CategoryType.eventsOnly
    ) {
      return;
    } else if (categoryType == CategoryType.weeklyEvent) {
      // For weekly events type `weeklyEvent` extra customization
      const _today = createTodayBasedOnTimezone(Default.timezone, new Date());
      const todayName = dayName(Default.locale, Default.timezone, _today);
      const todayNameToAccessId = todayName as keyof typeof WeeklyTagsIds;
      const selectedWeeklyEventTagId = WeeklyTagsIds[todayNameToAccessId];

      dispatch({
        type: "setSelectedVisualTagId",
        payload: selectedWeeklyEventTagId,
      });
    } else {
      onScrollingLoadMorePosts();
    }
  }, []);

  // starting point
  useEffect(() => {
    initializePosts();

    if (categoryType == CategoryType.allThings) {
      dispatch({ type: "setSelectedDate", payload: new Date() });
    }

    const selectedDate = state.selectedDate
      ? state.selectedDate.toString()
      : "";

    // Special case for weeklyEvent type
    if (categoryType == CategoryType.weeklyEvent && state.selectedVisualTagId) {
      loadMorePosts(
        categoryName,
        cityName,
        0,
        true,
        state.selectedVisualTagId,
        selectedDate,
        true // on initial call try to load all the featured post
      );
    } else if (categoryType != CategoryType.weeklyEvent) {
      // General case
      loadMorePosts(
        categoryName,
        cityName,
        0,
        true,
        state.selectedVisualTagId,
        categoryType == CategoryType.allThings
          ? new Date().toString()
          : selectedDate,
        true // on initial call try to load all the featured post
      );
    }
  }, [state.selectedVisualTagId, state.selectedLocationIds]);

  function createLogForClarity(category: string, filterName: string) {
    const logName =
      ClarityEvents.filter +
      category.replace(/ /g, "_") +
      "_" +
      filterName.replace(/ /g, "_");
    logClarity(logName);
  }

  const showTimeOnly = categoryType == CategoryType.weeklyEvent;

  const onFilterButtonClick = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "setTempSelectedLocationIds",
      payload: [...state.selectedLocationIds],
    });
    dispatch({ type: "setShowFilterPopupDialog", payload: true });
    logClarity(ClarityEvents.locationFilter);
  };

  const onFilterPopupCloseClick = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "setShowFilterPopupDialog", payload: false });
  };

  const onFilterPopupClearClick = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "setTempSelectedLocationIds", payload: [] });
  };

  const onFilterPopupApplyClick = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "setShowFilterPopupDialog", payload: false });
    dispatch({
      type: "selectedLocationIds",
      payload: [...state.tempSelectedLocationIds],
    });
  };

  const onAddRemoveSelectedLocationId = (id: number) => {
    let newIds: number[] = [];
    if (state.tempSelectedLocationIds.includes(id)) {
      newIds = state.tempSelectedLocationIds.filter((sId) => {
        return sId != id;
      });
    } else {
      newIds = state.tempSelectedLocationIds;
      newIds.push(id);
    }
    dispatch({ type: "setTempSelectedLocationIds", payload: newIds });
  };

  const onClearAllSelectionLocationIds = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "setTempSelectedLocationIds", payload: [] });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FilterPopupDialog
        isShowing={state.showFilterPopupDialog}
        onClose={onFilterPopupCloseClick}
        onClear={onFilterPopupClearClick}
        onApply={onFilterPopupApplyClick}
        locations={locations}
        selectedLocationIds={state.selectedLocationIds}
        tempSelectedLocationIds={state.tempSelectedLocationIds}
        onFilterAreaButtonSelect={onAddRemoveSelectedLocationId}
        onClearAllSelectionLocationIds={onClearAllSelectionLocationIds}
      />
      <div className="flow-col space-y-4 w-96">
        {state.visualTags && (
          <div className="flex py-2 sticky top-[64px] z-10 bg-white">
            <div className="flex w-24 pl-4 pr-2">
              <FilterButton onClick={onFilterButtonClick} />
            </div>
            <PostVisualTags
              visualTags={state.visualTags}
              onVisualTagChange={(selectedVisualTagId) => {
                const visualTagName =
                  state.visualTags?.filter(
                    (tag) => tag.id == selectedVisualTagId
                  )[0]?.name ?? "";
                createLogForClarity(categoryName, visualTagName);
                dispatch({
                  type: "setSelectedVisualTagId",
                  payload: selectedVisualTagId,
                });
              }}
              categoryType={categoryType}
              selectedVisualTag={state.selectedVisualTagId}
            />
          </div>
        )}

        {isEventsOnlyCategory && (
          <div
            className="border border-gray-300 rounded-2xl px-4 py-2 mx-4 text-center cursor-pointer font-bold text-slate-700"
            onClick={() => {
              logClarity(ClarityEvents.dateFilter);
              setShowingCalendar(!showingCalendar);
            }}
          >
            {" "}
            <span className="px-2">
              {state.selectedDate ? formatDate(state.selectedDate) : "Anytime"}
            </span>
            {state.selectedDate && (
              <span className="justify-end inline-flex">
                <button
                  className="p-1 rounded-md bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-300 "
                  onClick={removeSelectedDate}
                >
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    className="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  >
                    <path
                      fill="none"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M6 6l12 12M6 18L18 6"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        )}

        {showingCalendar && (
          <div className="fixed left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 bg-white border shadow-lg z-50">
            <CalendarWidget
              selectedDate={state.selectedDate ?? new Date()}
              onDateSelect={onSelectedDate}
            />
          </div>
        )}
        {state.featuredPosts &&
          state.featuredPosts.map((post) => (
            <div key={"featured:" + post.id}>
              <PostCategoryListItemCard
                key={"featuredCard:" + post.id}
                post={post}
                locale={locale}
                timezone={timezone}
                selectedDate={state.selectedDate}
                showTimeOnly={showTimeOnly}
                isFeatured
                city={cityName}
              />
            </div>
          ))}

        {state.posts &&
          state.posts.map((post) => (
            <div key={post.id} ref={lastElementRef}>
              <PostCategoryListItemCard
                key={post.id}
                post={post}
                locale={locale}
                timezone={timezone}
                selectedDate={state.selectedDate}
                showTimeOnly={showTimeOnly}
                city={cityName}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        {state.isFetching && (
          <div>
            <DotWave />
          </div>
        )}
        {!state.hasMore && !state.isFetching && (
          <div className="max-w-sm mx-4">
            <ButtonExploreMore
              city={cityName}
              isEventsOnly={isEventsOnlyCategory}
              onNextDate={gotoNextDate}
            />
          </div>
        )}
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;


How did you confirm that the useEffect hook is not firing? If you put a console.log as the first line of the hook, do you see it get logged to the console? It's hard to give a helpful answer without seeing more of the code.

Yes, I put a console.log() to test that. I updated the page with full source code on that particular page. Thank you for your help.

I fixed it by using dynamic() to load client component. The problem only occurred in the production mode. Using dynamic() solves the problem.
const Header = dynamic(() => import("@/app/Header"));

